# Can I pass dynamic parameter to a single report in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have **single report** in which I need to display different parameters based on different values from one table.

That is, if my table has value1(I'll get this value using SP), then(as my value is value1) I need to display 4 parameter fields in report  and
         if my table has value2(I'll get this value using SP), then(as my value is value2) I need to display 6 parameter fields in the report.

Is it possible? if yes how?

Note: I have developed some of the reports but has never come accross such situation before.Plaese help.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, are you trying to have a report call a stored proc with different number of parameters?

Comment: You want to hide/show the available parameters based on values in your result set? I don't think this is possible as the boxes that denote the type of parameter (hidden/internal) don't allow expressions to be assigned, not to mention the logic around dependent parameters which would get quite complex

Answer (score 0):

You can load a parameter field dynamically with a query but you can't add / remove them in the report dynamically.
You can try two options to achieve your goal:

- You create all the parameters and you load/clear them conditionally with an
  expression ([Expression Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157328.aspx) (Report Builder and SSRS))
- You create your own form in Asp.Net then you have a full control over
  the form and the parameters and you display your report with the report viewer control